# Using Photorec after accidentally deleting Users folder in Mac using rm -rf ~/

Tags: data-recovery, macintosh, macos, system-recovery

I copied this command online to the terminal without reading what it actually does (I know this is very dumb for a beginner) and suddenly, it started to delete every important file in the hard drive.

I forced restarted the laptop to see if it stops the deleting process but to my surprise, after logging in the standard macbookpro#, all files were deleted.

I didn't set up Time Machine or backups so I logged in to the Admin account (initially) without any file contained and downloaded Photorec to recover files, and stored them into the documents folder in the admin account. It's still in the process of recovering files (with estimated time for completion of 7 hours and my elapsed time is still in the first two hours).

Is it guaranteed that all my files in the macbrookpro# user will be recovered? I read online that if some of the files are overwritten then there is no way to actually recover those files, I don't really know how all of these works. What actions should I take aside from not taking any dumb decisions such as copy pasting random bits of command or codes from the internet?

Comment: What is your question? No, it's not guaranteed. First of all, you should have booted to a Live OS, that does not write to your hard drive (and overwrites your deleted files) and use `photorec` again or/and create a disk image with which to work. And to your last question: (1) Think before doing  (2) Have a Backup ready! There is nothing to prevent yourself doing bad stuff.

Comment: When you remove files, all you do is remove the information where the data is located. Photorec goes through the hard disk and examines disk blocks. It finds blocks that look like they might contain file data, thus recreating your files. It uses heuristics and can't guarantee reconstruction of all files. Disk blocks that are marked as free (because you removed the file) can be overwritten with other data. Once that happens, obviously there is nothing that can get the original contents back, except with special, expensive forensics tools and skills. Good luck.

Comment: Do you use Time machine? If so this will by far be the best way of recovering your data.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you "shot yourself in the foot--***TWICE***". The first time was when you deleted all your files. The second time when you rebooted from the same damaged disk to try to recover it. PHOTOREC works because file systems use the lazy approach to file deleting: They do not delete the data in the file, they only mark the space used by the file as being available for re-use. As long as nothing re-uses the space, PHOTOREC can recover it by marking it in use again. But when you booted back in to the drive, several things happen which may write to the disk and clobber those files because they're marked "free space" now. Many system processes read/write to the disk quite often, and have a high chance of overwriting your previous data and make it not recoverable.

You might recover some files, but most likely, you will not be able to recover many of them.

For what to do in the future: As soon as you do whatever you do to kill them system (power off may lose data in itself, but still the best bet, as the data loss is only a fraction compared to "everything"!) Then remove the hard drive from the system! Put it on a shelf and do not touch it again until you can get a safe environment for recovery.

Some people may say "no need to remove the drive", but I strongly suggest you do. Even if you are trying to boot to another drive or a "Live CD/DVD" (or USB), you may need to first get in to the BIOS to make sure it will boot from the alternate drive/CD/DVD/USB without trying to touch the damaged drive. It will also give you a chance to boot in to the safe system with the drive still removed, and ****practice**** doing the recovery commands to make sure you know how they work and what to expect before trying them on the damaged drive. This also includes things like learning how to mount the drive ****READ ONLY**** so it does not write to the drive (when you do the recovery, copy it from the damaged drive to a fresh new drive; Do not try to recover it back to the damaged disk, as you risk damaging the damaged parts further.)

Only after you have set up a safe recovery environment, practiced and made sure you understand the process from start to finish, and so on, should you put the drive back in (or get an external USB enclosure to turn it in to an external drive), mount it read-only, and recover it to another drive. You will likely still lose some files, but if you act deliberately and carefully, you can minimize the risks. And you can keep the damaged drive on the shelf until you're certain you've recovered all you can--PHOTOREC might make an update next month that can now recover some more files that the current one could not. So it is worth it to keep the drive laying around a few weeks to months. (I have one drive that got clobbered by a failed drive controller six years ago--that every now and then, I can still manage to recover yet another unique and precious family photo by using new techniques! It depends on what you feel is valuable enough and worth it.)